# Flash not work in iframe within sandbox attribute

Tags: html, flash, iframe, sandbox

I've used `iframe` to show some pages.These pages may contain an `adobe flash` content like a video.
my problem is that the `abode flash` doesn't execute in an `iframe` within sandbox attribute.
my `iframe` tag :

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-popups allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-scripts" src="http://example.com"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: you can't execute flash plugin in a sandboxed iframe.

The spec : http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-iframe-sandbox

> Plugins that cannot be secured are disabled in sandboxed browsing
>   contexts because they might not honor the restrictions imposed by the
>   sandbox (e.g. they might allow scripting even when scripting in the
>   sandbox is disabled). User agents should convey the danger of
>   overriding the sandbox to the user if an option to do so is provided.

For comprehensive information about sandbox attribute: http://blog.dareboost.com/en/2015/07/securing-iframe-sandbox-attribute/