# SandBoxed Error When Displaying PDF in HTML Element

Tags: html, google-chrome, pdf

I am using the following code to display a PDF document in an HTML element.

```
<embed src="PDFURL" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="474px" />
```

Whenever the code is run in Firefox it works perfectly, however when run in Chrome it returns this error in the console:

"Failed to load 'PDFURL' as a plugin, because the frame into which the plugin is loading is sandboxed."

I have changing "embed" to "object" and "iframe" but neither have worked. Is there a solution to get it to work in Chrome?

Comment: can you try 
- clearing cookies and cache 
- trying using incognito window 
- try using Chrome with all extensions + plugins disabled, I've seen things like Grammarly cause issues

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason for this problem is the Content Security Policy “sandbox” header.

> **sandbox**
> Enables a sandbox for the requested resource similar to the iframe sandbox attribute. The sandbox applies a same origin policy, prevents popups, plugins and script execution is blocked.

(The whole description can be found under https://content-security-policy.com/)

Unfortunately, the only possible way to get this working is to remove the sandbox value from Content Security Policy. Because there is no possible value to enable plugins.

The sandbox header works the same way as the sandbox attribute for iframe. 
See also [Flash not work in iframe within sandbox attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26412210/flash-not-work-in-iframe-within-sandbox-attribute)